# Servlet Filter as Security Proxy for Web Services

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee

Good time.

Suppose there are 8 web-services in the one application. 5 of them require authorization (a client must to provide a JSESSIONID cookie and a corresponding session must not be invalidated), other 3 can be called without the jsessionid cookie. My naive solution is to write a servlet filter which intercepts requests and retrieve their pathInfos (all the services have the same url structure: /service/**serviceSuffix**). There is a enum which contains the **serviceSuffix** of each web service that requires authorization. When the request is retrieved the pathInfo is collected; if this pathInfo is contained in the enum and there is the corresponding valid session the request is sent ahead to the filter chain. Otherwise, an error is sent back to a client. After a while I've realized that it is needed to add the possibility to retrieve the wsdl and xsds for the concrete service. So that, two more check were added.

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

public static final String WSDL = "wsdl";
public static final String XSD = "xsd=";

/**
 * Wittingly left empty
 */
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    String pathInfo = servletRequest.getPathInfo();
    String queryString = servletRequest.getQueryString();

    if (pathInfo != null && SecureWebServices.contains(pathInfo)) {
        if (queryString != null && (queryString.equals(WSDL) || queryString.startsWith(XSD))) {
            // wsdl or xsd is requested
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        } else {
            // a web service's method is called
            HttpSession requestSession = servletRequest.getSession(false);
            if (requestSession != null) { // the session is valid
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                servletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

/**
 * Wittingly left empty
 */
public void destroy() {}

}
```

It seems that it is not very secure, because if the request's pathInfo is not in the enum, this request is passed on (just in case of some unexpected system calls).

**Could you, please, suggest what to do, how to increase the security level**. I want to build a configurable system (that is why I have the enum. It is possible just to add a path there to secure the web service and it is not required to duplicate the security code in the each web service). How to increase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand but.

jsessionid has nothink to do with security. you simply just get it.

Next I am not sure if you want authentication or authorization. The code as provided will not provide you with security features.

I suppose you are interested in authentication anyway. Security logic can be provided with standard web container features. Just send in authentication data in the header of request and you are done. web container can be configured to secure only selected resources (urls)